# Execute another PHP script

Tags: php

I have a **cron job** that calculates the disk space on *ServerA*

I have a MySQL database on *ServerB* that stores the disk space values

*ServerA* in not allowed to access MySQL database on *ServerB* (Rules out direct MySQL Connect)

*ServerA* cannot open files on *ServerB* (Rules out `include();`)

*ServerA* and *ServerB* have no `shell_exec()` abilities

I've tried `header("Location: http://ServerB.com/record.php?disk_space=$disk_space");` using a get method then the receiving file `$_REQUEST` the values but it only works when run through browser and not when run as a cron job.

I think there are no proper alternatives. But I'm happy with a peculiar or scruffy solution. Please put forward your ideas. TIA

Comment: curl, file_get_contents() or even wget from a cron job would all work fine

Comment: This boils down to a question of what network protocol you'd like to use. If the MySQL server also runs a web server, you can treat that side like a normal dynamic webpage and just hit the URL from the cron job (via PHP itself or wget, curl, etc). Depending on your setup you may want more security in this layer, in which case SSH or something similar might be a better choice. Do you have any restrictions/preferences in this regard?

Answer (score 2):

You can hit external scripts directly through a number of HTTP libraries -- as well as `file_get_contents()`.

See:

- [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) - accepts a URL as the filename
- [curl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) - HTTP library
- [HTTP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.http.php) - another HTTP library

You could even use [sockets](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php) to make the request:

Lots of options (more than included here). Easiest, if your needs are simple, is just `file_get_contents`.

Answer (score 0):

create a file with an extension of php and write your script with mysqli_connect, etc and handle what you want to do as if you go the this page on your browser yourself than run cron job of that file , that should do it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the cron file must be executed from a separate server from where the MySQL server is hosted and running `mysqli_connect` will not work from external servers.